# UIPopoverPresentationController not showing in the right position

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, device-orientation, uipopover

I have a popover where the SourceRect is the setting button (the button with a gear icon).
The popover position is correct for all device orientation except for LandscapeLeft.

I set the anchor from XCode Interface builder and set the source rect programmatically:

```
var poc = segue.DestinationViewController as PVPencilOptionsController;
poc.ViewModel = this.ViewModel.ColorPicker;
var ppc = (UIPopoverPresentationController)poc.PresentationController;
ppc.SourceRect = this.PVEditIssuePhotoPencilOptionsButton.Frame;
```

Below are the result of popover position:

Portrait/upside down (correct):

[image: Portrait and upside down]

Landscape Right (correct):

[image: Landscape Right]

Landscape Left (wrong)

[image: Landscape Left]

As you can see, if the device orientation is Landscape Left, there is a gap between the popover arrow and the setting button.

How to find out where this gap come from?

Answer (score 1):

I've had simlar issues and mine was all due to the fact that I was calculating my sizing and my positioning in the wrong place, sometimes using the wrong values as well. There's two things I would suggest to find your problem:

**1. Do all position/sizing calculations in LayoutSubviews:** Override the LayoutSubviews in your controller and calculate your positioning information in there. After the base call.

**2. Log out dimensions of Frame as well as Bounds:** This way you can see what you have and where you want it to be. Do this before and after layout subviews to see the difference.

Comment: I tried both your solutions but I still can't find the problem. The frame and bounds are correct, the SourceRect position too.

Comment: @currarpickt that's a bummer. The other way i solve positioning and sizing issues id by setting the background colors of the items i'm trying to position, and the item's that it's placed in. Just to see if everything is as expected. That's the only other way i can see you getting closer to solving this.

Comment: I've tried that one to, changed every background colours and everything is in the right position.